# Possible bug with jupyter notebook, when using warnings.simplefilter('error')?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I run the following code, and jupyter notebooks seems to get stuck:

```
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter('error')
```

When trying to run any more code, nothing happens.

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with that code?

Comment: Well, from what I understand, it turns warnings into exceptions. I didn't want to use it for anything. It is part of a library which I needed, and when I imported it, jupyter got stuck.